# set user id as the current user in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have a userId - `$uid`.

I wanted to make this user as logged in to the s/m in joomla.

I've tried this -

```
$currentUser = new JUser($uid);

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$credentials = array();
$credentials['username'] = $currentUser->username;
$credentials['password'] = $currentUser->password; //this is the hashed password

//perform the login action
$mainframe->login($credentials);

$newuser = JFactory::getUser(); //this doesn't get updated to the new user ($uid) details
```

How can I make the user as the current user by using the uid itself?

**Update**: I just found that user can be loaded with JUser::load()

Trial 2-

```
$user = JUser::getInstance($uid);
$user->load($uid); //this should load the new user.

$newuser = JFactory::getUser(); //still i get the anonymous details here 
            //($newuser->id = 0)
```

As there is `wp_set_current_user($uid);` for wordpress `user_load_by_name()` in drupal, is there any similar function for joomla ? Please help.!!!

Thanks!

Comment: Note - If I add the hardcoded password to $credentials['password'], it works. But I can't hardcode it, can i get the unhashed passwd from the hashed one?

Comment: you cant get the original Joomla! password

Comment: thought so!, can I log the user with $uid from the code ?

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but it can help someone in the future.
In order to set the user for JFactory::getUser(), you need to set it in the session:

```
JFactory::getSession()->set('user', JFactory::getUser($uid));
```

Comment: this only set user in current session. If you want to login this use onto site, you can check https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15368/set-user-id-as-the-current-user-in-joomla/16632#16632

Comment: it's not very clear in the question. Does he really wants to 'login' the user, or to force the user for the JFactory::getUser() response...

Comment: This worked for me, that I needed to load some product prices for a specific shopper group in Virtuemart in the back-end, where the current user is the admin, but we wanted to retrieve prices for a specific front-end user. Just a note: I kept the original user in a temprorary variable to re-set it in the same way after doing my calculations, because otherwise it disconnected the active user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much knowledge about Joomla so I was not able to implement it but here is my idea:

I remembered that there was a *switch user* plugin for joomla. I searched for it and found [this](https://www.artd.ch/component/k2/item/174-switch-user-plugin-for-joomla-3-x.html). It should be possible to port this code to change user by user-id, like you need it. Noting else they are doing after clicking on the link in admin-cp.